# PPA keeps downloading kodi 18 instead of kodi 17

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 very successfully.
My problem is that I am trying to download kodi 17 Krypton. Instead I keep getting kodi 18. the unreleased version of kodi. I understand that this is referred to as the "nightly" version. I follow all the commands to remove the installation but each time I reinstall kodi I end up with the same version.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove kodi*
sudo apt-get purge kodi*
```

Reinstall.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Installation commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y -r ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kodi
```

I then end up with kodi 18.0 alpha.

How can I install Kodi 17?

Comment: Did you accidentally install `ppa:team-xbmc/xbmc-nightly` as well? For that one contains version 2.18. Remove it by `sudo ppa-purge team-xmbc/xbmc-nightly` (perhaps `sudo apt install ppa-purge` first).

Comment: when you execute `sudo apt-get remove kodi` what output do you get?

Comment: OK I used both your commands and then sudo apt-get kodi. The terminal went back to normal prompt and kodi seemed to have been removed.

Comment: Shall I now try to reinstall kodi?

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 kodi : Depends: kodi-bin (< 2:16.1~git20160425.1001-final-0xenial.1~) but 2:17.1~git20170320.2031-final-0xenial is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken

Comment: This is result of trying to reinstall kodi? Can you advise on next move please?

Comment: @Rinzwind  Kodi is a media center, and it's among apps added to official Ubuntu repositories.  I've Kodi 15.0 for instance.  It's perfectly on-topic :)

Comment: Give the output of `apt policy kodi`. Sounds like you've added nightly ppas. I tested your command, It only shows version 17 for me